# connection results (multiple tables) php, mysqli INNER JOIN

Tags: mysqli, inner-join

(Best practice for including many to many results inside each result?)

Each post has a number of resources. I'm trying to show them.
It works separately, like this:

All connections between resources and posts:

```
   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *
        FROM kopplaKontorsplatsResurser
        INNER JOIN resurser
        ON kopplaKontorsplatsResurser.resurs_id=resurser.id
        ");

    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo 'Resource with id: '.$row[resurs_id];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Is connected to the post: '.$row[kontorsplats_id];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'What resource is this? '.$row[resurs];;
    echo '<br><br>';
    }
```

This is how I get info about each post(kontorsplats)

```
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *
                 FROM kontorsplatser
                 INNER JOIN geo_orter
                 ON kontorsplatser.ort_id=geo_orter.ort_id
                 ");
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo '<div class="kontorsplats">';
    $arbetsplatsensID = $row[id];
    $rubriken = $row[rubrik];
    $ort_id = $row[ort_id];
    $ort = $row[ortnamn];

    echo '<h4>'.$rubriken.'</h4>';
    echo '<h5><a href="">'.$ort.'</a></h5>';

       ---> Show the connected resources here. :D <------

    echo '</div>';
```

I'm considering creating an array with all the resources and their connections and loop through it for every div, but would that be the most efficient way?

Interresting on including aliases:
[devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/alias-in-inner-join-query-512683.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, still have the lingering feeling that it's not optimal, but it works!

First Save all connections and resources into an array

```
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *
        FROM kopplaKontorsplatsResurser
        INNER JOIN resurser
        ON kopplaKontorsplatsResurser.resurs_id=resurser.id
        ");
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $dennaKontorsplats = $row[kontorsplats_id];
        $resursens_id = $row[resurs_id];
        $resurskopplingar[$dennaKontorsplats][$resursens_id] = $row[resurs];
    }
```

Then loop through it for each post

```
//Leta upp alla resurskopplingar: 
    foreach ($resurskopplingar as $kontoretsid => $lvl1) {
        if($arbetsplatsensID == $kontoretsid){
        foreach ($lvl1 as $lvl2) {
            echo $lvl2;
        }
        }
    }
```